# C:linked list prints junk characters

Tags: c

Here is a piece of code that i wrote which adds the name of the persons in a linked list.The problem is faced when I am trying to display those names.Instead of printing the names , my code prints junk characters
Code...

```
struct node
{
 char name1[5];
 struct node *link;
};


void add(struct node **q,char *name)
{
 struct node *temp,*r;
 if(*q==NULL)
 {
             temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             *temp->name1=name;
             temp->link=NULL;
             *q=temp;
             count++;
 }
 else
 {
     count++;
     temp=*q;
     while(temp->link !=NULL)
     temp=temp->link;

     r=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     *r->name1=name;
     r->link=NULL;
     temp->link=r;
 }    

} 



void display(struct node *q)
{
    while(q!=NULL)
     {
      printf("%s",q->name1);  //it prints junk characters
      q=q->link;
      }                   

}     
int main()
{
    struct node *p;
    p=NULL;

    add(&p,"Alice");
    add(&p,"Cat");
    add(&p,"Pawan");
    add(&p,"BoB");

    display(p);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're getting some answers that tell you what's wrong with your code, but for future reference you could have found some bugs yourself simply by compiling with warnings enabled.  For example, compiling your exact code with `gcc -Wall` told me exactly what @unwind's answer points out.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
*temp->name1=name;
```

doesn't do what you expect, at all. It converts the address of the `name` string into a character, and sets the first character of `temp1->name1` to that value.

This bad conversion should have generated compiler warnings: make sure you enable all warnings your compiler is capable of, and *fix* them.

To correct the code, you need to actually copy the string data:

```
strcpy(temp->name1, name);
```

Note that this is very dangerous if `name` is longer than `name1` supports, i.e. more than 4 characters plus terminating 0-character. You can make it safer by using:

```
strlcpy(temp->name1, name, sizeof temp->name1);
```

if you have it, or

```
snprintf(temp->name1, sizeof temp->name1, "%s", name);
```

if you have that.

Comment: ITYM `strncpy` or `strncpy_s` (C11) instead of `strlcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

You `char name1[5]` array is too small. "Alice" is 6 characters because of the terminating NUL, but your array is only 5 chars, leading to **undefined behavior** in C parlance. As unwind points out, there's also an extra dereference bug in `*temp->name1` which probably should be `temp->name1`.